# mysql update or insert to another table using subquery that returns x amount of rows

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have been trying for about 8 hours now and to no avail. I am trying to update or insert the AVG of 2 to 10 rows from a single column into another table.

The code I use right now to calculate the average.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), NAME, AVG(AVERAGE) FROM table1 GROUP BY NAME ORDER BY NAME;
```

This returns the proper results as I used group by as a workaround but now I need to get that data into another table.

However when I try to run update or insert mysql always complains about a multi line subquery return.

How can I get this into table2 where the name matches and into column average of table2? The name is 100% unique. I also would like the names to match. This will be updated maybe once a day.

EDIT:
First table ENTRY_ID, NAME(not unique for multiple entries), AVERAGE 
Second table has ID(unique), NAME(unique), AVERAGE

I have tried so many queries its not funny I've searched all the documentation I'm just not putting something together right.

When you run the above it might have 8 rows it runs AVG(AVERAGE) maybe 6 they are matched by name.

I want to store them in table2 where the name in table1 matches the name in table2 but just gives the single average of the above query.

Thanks

EDIT2: This is the code that worked

`INSERT INTO table2 (NAME, AVERAGE)
(SELECT * FROM
(SELECT NAME, AVG(AVERAGE) as AVERAGE
FROM table1
GROUP BY NAME) main_query)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE table2.AVERAGE = main_query.AVERAGE;`

Thanks to @ARubiksCube

Comment: Share details of other table. Also update the question with query you are using to update/insert.

Comment: Note that generally you wouldn't store derived data

Comment: you should post some data of both tables.

Comment: Edited for more details. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure of what your actual error message is. My guess is that you are using a newer version of MYSQL so you are getting this error.

This query will update all the records in table2 with the values from table1. If the record does not exist, it will be inserted. If the record exists, It will be updated.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (NAME, AVERAGE)
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT NAME, AVG(AVERAGE) as AVERAGE
FROM table1
GROUP BY NAME) main_query
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE table2.AVERAGE = main_query.AVERAGE;
```

Comment: I thought it would be this simple as well, sadly... #1062 - Duplicate entry '16' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: @Xofraz I updated my answer with a query that should work

Comment: thats is exactly what I'm looking, but now error #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, before i run it phpmyadmin gives Unexpected keyword. (near "ON" at position 127)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "ON" at position 127). Also I have to take out entry_id because those are incremental and unique.

Comment: I updated it again, assuming table2 has 'unique' set on the 'NAME' and 'ID' Column. If not, run `ALTER TABLE table2 ADD UNIQUE (ID)` or/and `ALTER TABLE table2 ADD UNIQUE (NAME)`. Also, this query will not work if NAME is a 'text' field. When testing, I am using a 'varchar'

Comment: Thank you it worked I did have to take out the () on the first SELECT. I will update with what works in a few minutes, I want to make 100% sure the values are right. EDIT: actually a bit confused first time i had to remove () second I didnt.

Comment: It should work either way, I guess. Honestly I do not know why you had to remove them the first time.

Comment: Yeah it works either way and the values match up. I can apply this to my main db tables now and has worked thank you so much, I see what i was doing wrong earlier and just got a needed lesson in `ON DUPLICATE KEY` as well as `INSERT INTO`. as well as how to properly use subquery.